Would mining asteroids cause meteorites
I wanted to know if the mining of Asteroids would cause a problem with meteorites for nearby planets. Like if a company came in and started blowing up moons, asteroids or dwarf planets would the debris make its way to nearby planets and enter the atmosphere?
For the story that I'm using this scenario in, several astronomical bodies are being blown up and mined. So would the larger planets in the system feel any repercussions from the debris? I'm curious about how the planet's gravitational pull or the astronomical bodies' distance would influence potential meteorites. I was looking at other posts but I didn't see anything that specifically discussed how larger debris would behave once the original object was blown up.

Why would mining group run the risk of causing mineral laden rock to be thrown out of reach? Explosive energy to break rock apart is Kg of TNT, Explosive energy to cause notable meteorites is Ktonnes  of TNT

Depends on how the mining company treats their workers.

Scenario 1:
Company redirects a big asteroid into planetary orbit (as it is easier to work on it while closer to the planet), then makes controlled explosion to crack it into smaller manageable parts and expose asteroid core. What could go wrong? If company wrongly measured asteroid composition, it could explode into a cloud of sparse gravel instead of a few big pieces. Such cloud would expand around whole orbit and make it (orbit) inhabitable to any satellites or manned spaceflight.
Scenario 2:
As company is redirecting asteroid into low planetary orbit, it loses control over used machinery, maybe an accident, maybe a terrorist attack, and asteroids gets into collision course instead.
Scenario 3:
When company tried to crack asteroid open using explosives while in low orbit, it did not absorb the explosive energy to crack, instead the explosion lowered its orbital speed. Or it maybe exposed hidden gasses in it and as they out-gassed out of cracked crust, that caused the change in orbital speed. As orbital speed dropped, the asteroid went into descending orbit and got eventually caught by an atmosphere.
Scenario 4:
Company put asteroid into a highly elliptical orbit, with the lowest point of it being very close to the planet. There are many advantages to such orbits, which are for longer explanation. While the asteroid was near its highest orbit point, something exploded on it and slightly changed the orbital speed, maybe a faulty machinery, maybe exposed underground gasses. Due to how elliptical orbit mechanics work, even small change to an orbital speed on its highest point causes amplified change to orbital height on its lowest point. And now the lowest point of said orbit collides with a planet.

A factor to take into account is that it takes quite a lot of energy to move stuff between orbits because of the sun's gravity well: Different orbits have different potential energies and require different velocities for circular orbits. Hence, it makes more sense to mine and refine matertal at an asteroid than to move the asteroid to a different orbit.

@KlausÆ.Mogensen I fully agree, however, without redirection of the asteroid closer to the planet, any catastrophic event is highly unlikely and thus making the story implausible. Hence why I strongly advocated for it.

Yes, it is possible that explosions can cause meteorites: escape velocities for asteroids are in the order of few m/s, and such velocities are also achieved by the fragments resulting from an explosion.
However:

the size of these fragments is usually well below the size needed for a meteorite to survive atmospheric reentry
the ejection direction would be random, resulting a cloud originating from the asteroid and expanding outwards

More than a threat for the planet, I would that is a threat for the operation on and around the asteroid.
Top it with the related waste of potential ores and related income, I guess the mining company would resort to other methods than blowing explosives near the surface.

If they are going to use explosives, they'll be deep charges and the entire rock will be covered in some kind of wrap before blowing the charge. Just enough explosives to break the rock, not enough to break the surrounding wrap.

"… to survive atmospheric reentry" — Do I understand it correctly that this is only true for Earth and other planets with a thick atmosphere like ours – but not necessarily for other planets, like Mercury? Or in other words, it also depends on how thick the atmosphere is.

I expect the ships to haul in the asteroid and crunch them up (in a controlled chamber), before sending them into some sort of oven to melt them, extracting resources. The only reason to blow them apart would be to reduce their size to workable chunks. The only pieces escaping there are going to be orders of magnitude below what they would like to work with. Thus depending on what scale the resource collection works.

Unlikely
To start with, with the likely size of the fragments coming off the asteroid, not a single one is making it to the ground of a planet with a dense atmosphere. However, if they are big and fast enough, they could theoretically damage nearby space stations or domes on uninhabitable moons. However, space is big, and they would have to be really close for any real danger. If they were right next to it, maybe, but there is basically no way that mining in the asteroid belt will send dangerous meteorites to Europa.

Or more precisely, any such fragments would be comparable to the debris which bodies in space are already routinely exposed to. If a planet's atmosphere protects its inhabitants from natural spaceborne rocks, it'll protect them from unnatural ones of similar size, mass, and velocity.
